# Decreasing flex growth without affecting equal difference

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a navigation that stretches across the whole page by using `flex-growth` and `flex-basis` properties.

HTML:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <body>
            <div id="main_navigator">
                <div id="main_navigator_upper">          
                    <a id="main_navigator_logo" src="/"></a>
                    <ul id="main_navigator_r1">
                        <li>
                            <a class="main_nav_btn">BTN 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="main_nav_btn">BTN 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="main_nav_btn">BTN 3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="main_nav_btn">BTN 4</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div id="main_navigator_s1"></div>
                        </li>
                <li>
                  <ul id="main_navigator_regbox">
                    <li>
                      <p id="regbox_signin">sign in</p>
                    </li>
                    <li id="main_navigator_l1">
                      <div id="main_navigator_regbox_s1"></div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a id="regbox_signup" href="sign_up">sign up</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                          </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

In order to make these elements stretch through the whole screen by their width, I can use this code:

```
#main_navigator_r1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    padding: 0;
    padding-right: 5%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0px;
    height: 98px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#main_navigator_r1 li {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-basis: 0;
}
```

which finally gives me [this result](https://jsfiddle.net/w5pL8fvw/7/).

But unfortunately, this doesn't look very pleasant - golden spacer's parent's width is too long, thus I solved this problem by decreasing `flex-growth` specifically for this list item, I gave list item its unique id `main_navigator_l1`.

```
#main_navigator_r1 li {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-basis: 0;
}
#main_navigator_l1 {
    flex-grow: 0.1 !important;
}
```

---

## Problem:

For some reason, as window gets smaller, spacer gets closer to the element on the right side and this affects the symmetry between elements. You can see this by [scaling this page](https://jsfiddle.net/w5pL8fvw/10/embedded/result).

How can I decrease the size of one specific element of flexbox without affecting symmetry (`#main_navigator_l1` in this case)?

Thank you!

Comment: With `flex-basis: 0` you are distributing free space on the line *equally* among flex items, regardless of the length of their content. Because the last item has longer content than the first four (buttons), the divider appears to lean right (there's a shorter distance to the text).

Comment: What you need for the divider to remain centered is for `flex-basis` to distribute free space on the line *proportionally*. That is done with `flex-basis: auto`. Full details in the duplicate. https://jsfiddle.net/w5pL8fvw/11/

Comment: @Michael_B Heard of `flex-basis: auto` but never thought it would work this way. Thanks a lot!